# Quiero responder una request get por lo que diga el path, cómo lo hago?

Tags: php, web, http

La siguiente página que pondré es un ejemplo para poder dar a entender lo que quiero hacer:
`https://example.com/number/123456`

Bien, pues con un script php que se encuentre en el directorio /number/ quiero extraer lo que ingresen en el siguiente "directorio", o sea, el valor de la búsqueda sería `123456`

Para esto solamente lo quiero imprimir con un simple `echo`, obviamente no quiero hacer esto simplemente para imprimir el valor, pero quiero entenderlo antes de hacer otra cosa.

```
Request: https://example.com/number/123456
Expected Output: 123456
```

Gracias por sus aportaciones.

Comment: Has intentado obtener la URL e imprimirla al menos ?

Comment: No, cómo lo haría?, solo imprimiría el __dir__ pero del archivo

Comment: Revisa [`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

Lo obtienes de la siguiente manera

con  `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` obtienes `/number/123456`

con `explode()` cortas el string por el caracter `/`

Te queda un `array()` de la siguiente manera   `[0 => "",1=>"number",2=>"123456"]` nos interesa la posición numero `2` del `array`

El codigo completo es el siguiente:

```php
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$parametros = explode("/",$url);

var_dump($parametros[2]);
```